# Android Starting an Activity from different project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity, launch

I have 2 projects in Eclipse. When I click on a button in project1, I want it to launch an activity from project2.
how can I do that ?
i tried the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.project2.tp02.MainActivity.class);
intent.setClassName("com.project2.tp02", "com.project2.tp02.MainActivity.class");
startActivity(intent);
```

I get an error message telling that first application stopped. How can I lauch it properly without such error?

Thanks in advance to any helper.

---

I got it work using this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String pkg ="com.project2.tp02";
String clazz =pkg + ".MainActivity";
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(pkg, clazz));
startActivity(intent);
```

I don't understand why that way it works and not previous one, if someone can explain I will be thankfull, but anyway I got my problem solved that way.

Comment: Please provide the details of the exception, as there's not enough information here determine the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working code to invoke an activity which is in another project.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.my.package", "com.my.package.MyClass"));
startActivity(intent);
```

I think your first code did not work because you provide your current activity as context of invoked activity where it is in another application.

Comment: I think you are right, maybe the problem of first way comes from context...
Anyway the problem is solved, how can I tag it as resolved ? just by making a check near your answer ? I can't find any button called Resolved like in other forums ..

Comment: Yes, the green checkmark mark it as resolved... click up arrow to my answer could be good as well to mark this answer as useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.project2.tp02.MainActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Adding the above lines in the Manifest of your first activity might solve your problem.

Comment: Check this out for more :http://hmkcode.com/android-start-another-activity-of-another-application/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work :(
the first application crash, i get an error (unfortunatly application TP02 stopped)...

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting what the error message is saying exactly... you do need the intent-filter as described by Swayam on the activity you want to call.

Try 
new Intent("com.project2.tp02.MainActivity");
to get the intent, instead of setting the class name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help. I solved the problem with the way i mentioned above, but anyway am thankfull for your effort to trying to help